# Copy changing value to next cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here I have a excel "Lunchbox" Configurator.

To create a lunchbox you must choose 1 main, 1 side, 1 sweet. There are 3 availabe options for every main, side and sweet.

You can create a lunchbox configuration by selecting options from the dropdown list which will then display next to "Lunchbox combo".

I want to create a button that saves a configuration when the "save" button is pressed. This will place the luncbox combo next to day one. When a new configuration is created and the save button is pressed, it wil copy the text next to day 2. Creating a 3rd configuation a saving it will place it next to day 3 and so on.

I am only know starting to learn vba so any help or solutions will greatly be appreciated! Thanks :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ou04.png)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's elementary associate this macros on a button

```
Sub SaveLunch
For i=8 to 15 
if Cells(i,7)<>0 Then Cells(i,7)=Cells(6,7)
next i
End Sub
```